# How do you get Posts by multiple meta_keys and meta_values with the Rest API V2?

Tags: metadata, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to get my Posts by multiple `meta_key`s and `meta_value`s. How do I accomplish this? The URL should be looking like this:

```
"/posts?meta_key=Example&meta_value=Example2&meta_key=Example3&meta_value=Example4"
```

I tried to find a solution for this quite a while now, but couldn't find anything as most things were outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my Problem. What i did is quite simple. I just setted up a new Query Params.

```
if (!function_exists('post_meta_rest_api_request')) :
function post_meta_rest_api_request($argu, $request)
{

    $argu += array(
        'meta_key' => $request['meta_key'],
        'meta_value' => $request['meta_value'],
        'meta_query' => $request['meta_query'] == 1 ? array(
        array(
            "key" => "key1",
            "value" => "value1"
        ),
        array(
            "key" => "key2",
            "value" => "value2"
        )
    ) : $request['meta_query']
    );

    return $argu;
}
add_filter('rest_custom_query', 'post_meta_rest_api_request', 99, 2); 
endif;
```

So if you now make an API call like: `wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/customType?meta_query=1`
the API Request will take in your custom Query Params. Otherwise it will just take in the normal Meta Query Request.
For references look here: [WordPress Rest-API Requests](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/requests/)